# Subtract values in Array2 from Array1 while keeping remaining duplicates

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Is it possible to subtract the values in one NSMutableArray from those in another NSMutableArray, while preserving any remaining like values (keep duplicate copies)? I don't want to remove every instance of the value, just a 1 for 1 subtraction.

I'm working with CGPoints.

**Array1**
ccp(1,1)
ccp(1,1)
ccp(1,2)
ccp(1,3)

**Array2**
ccp(1,1)

**Desired output: Array3**
ccp(1,1)
ccp(1,2)
ccp(1,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't understand your question properly before. Maybe you could try something like:

```
NSMutableArray *points1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 2)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 3)], nil];

NSArray        *points2 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)]];

NSInteger index = NSNotFound;

for (NSValue *point in points2) {
    index = [points1 indexOfObject:point];

    if (NSNotFound != index) {
        [points1 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", points1);

=> 2012-03-04 00:02:26.376 foobar[19053:f803] (
       "NSPoint: {1, 1}",
       "NSPoint: {1, 2}",
       "NSPoint: {1, 3}"
   )
```

---

**Update**

`NSNotFound` is defined in `NSObjCRuntime.h`. You can find this out by command + clicking on the symbol `NSNotFound` in Xcode.

The definition is

```
 enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};
```

The reason I knew to use this is by looking at the [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) documentation for the `indexOfObject:` method, which reads:

> **Return Value**
>   The lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject. If none of the objects in the array is equal to anObject, returns `NSNotFound`.

Comment: This works great, thanks! Could you comment on what exactly NSNotFound is doing? After reading up on it I think I understand what's going on, but it's not 100% clear for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vanny I've added some clarification

Comment: Thank for the very thorough answer, much appreciated. I wish I could upvote this answer, but I'm new.